# What happened to Walt's money when he fired Saul?

Tags: breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad* S3, Walt fires Saul who in revenge pulls the plug on the online money laundering to SaveWalterWhite.com.

At the time, I think we'd seen about $20-30k funneled into the system which is less than 10% of his cut from the initial deal with Gus.

Do we know what happens to the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Walt still has the money under the house somewhere, or wherever he hides it. The money which is getting laundered comes from there. So the 20-30K that got laundered are "safe", as in - legal, and the rest are still at the hideout.

Comment: You think he gave it to Saul as needed, not up front? That would make sense.

Comment: Is there a scene of Walter giving Sal a specific amount in order for it to get laundered, or a specific arrangement between the two in terms of when some money is to be exchanged and how?

Comment: No but I figured for Saul to pay his nerds, he'd need the money. However in S3:E5 Mas, Skylar talks to her counsellor about the money Walt keeps in the house so you must be right :)